# Swift: How to check for generic type in a reflection?

Tags: swift

I have following model:

```
class BaseClass { ... }
class WeakCollection<T: BaseClass> { ... }
class Person : BaseClass { ... }

class Parent : Person { 
    var children: [Child]
    ...
}

class Child : Person { 
    var parents: WeakCollection<Parent>
    ...
}

let aChild = Child()
...
```

I'm using a reflection like this:

```
let mirrored_object = Mirror(reflecting: aChild)
for attr in mirrored_object.children {
    switch attr.value {
         case is Int:
             ...

         case is String:
             ...

         case is WeakCollection<BaseClass>:
             ...
    }
}
```

The problem is the check in the `case is WeakCollection<BaseClass>` is always false if the generic type is not directly the `BaseClass` itself, that is if it is some of its subclasses this check will be false. How can I check for the generic type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rough way of doing that, is to make your "WeakCollection" inherit from some kind of protocol:

```
protocol BaseProtocol {}
class WeakCollection<T> : BaseProtocol
```

And then in your switch do it like this:

```
switch attr.value {
    case is String:
        // This is a string
        break
    case let optionalObject as Optional<Any>:
        if case .some(let complexObject) = optionalObject
        {
            if (complexObject is BaseProtocol)
            {
                // This is a "WeakCollection" kind
            }
        }
        break
}
```

This is a bit rough, but it gives out the output you want.

Comment: Much thanks, I have even tried just `case is BaseProtocol` with some constraints for the generic type and this works too. Funny how easy it is. Thanks for getting the right idea.

Comment: I'm facing another problem, how can I cast to a protocol if it contains an associatedtype? This gives me the error:  Protocol 'BaseProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Comment: What do you mean by "access"? What I'd do is create an extension from that protocol, and then you add "typealias" to the associated types in order to use them